# Shortest Sub-sequence Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

if we have two sequence X= and Y= of alphabet. we want to find shortest sequence such that X and Y becomes the sub-sequence of that sequence. what is the time complexity of this work?

1) O(nm)

2) O(n+m)

3) O((n+m)log(n+m))

My solution: i found a Dynamic Programming way and use O(nm) order. any idea to better solution ?

thanks to anyone

Comment: Must they become subsequences or substrings? Your text suggests subsequences and your tags suggest substrings.

Comment: If you had GHIJK and KLMNOP then the the answer would be GHIJKLMNOP?

Comment: Expected output for `abcde` and `bd` is `abcde` then?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce this problem to finding the longest common sub-sequence (LCS).

Given the two sequences and their longest common sub-sequence, you can construct the shortest super-sequence *in linear time* using a merge-like greedy algorithm, which adds letters from X or Y to the result if they are missing from the common sub-sequence, and advances to the next letter. It is trivial to show that this algorithm produces the shortest super-sequence, because otherwise it would be a contradiction with the assertion that we used the longest common sub-sequence.

Since none of the LCS solutions are linear, solving LCS will dominate the algorithm for finding the answer to this problem as well. The complexity of the solution to LCS depends on several factors, such as the length of the alphabet.

[A solution to the general LCS is O(n*m)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Reduce_the_problem_set).

A solution to LCS on a fixed alphabet is [O((n+m+c)*long(n+m))](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Further_optimized_algorithms), where `c` is the length of the common sub-sequence.

Comment: would you please say your idea about http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall14/CSCI-GA.1170-001/hw/hw7.pdf, in part b at question (2) says a O(mn)? i think this is the best time complexity? am i right?

Comment: @AliMovagher Yes, assuming that there are no further restrictions, the best you can do is O(m*n).